# Available updates report does not list all available module updates

Tags: 7, updating

I just noticed that the page `admin/reports/updates` highlights subsequent modules as I proceed with the upgrades. For example, initially the Webform and Token modules got the yellowish highlight, and then when I applied the updates to those two, refreshing the page highlighted subsequent modules, say: Date and Rules.

So, is there a particular logic in which the suggestions are made? And, can one get a COMPLETE list of update candidates at one shot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Drupal 7, two methods are used to fetch update information. One uses a setting `update_max_fetch_time` which is set to 5 seconds by default. On each cron run - whether from the server's cron or triggered by a visitor (poormanscron) - or page refresh of `admin/reports/updates`, this value is used. Not every module's status can be fetched within those 5 seconds, which is what you're seeing.

If you use the 'Check manually' link from the 'Available updates' page (`admin/reports/updates/check`), a batch operation is used instead, which should process all modules. There are however also reports that this doesn't always work correctly (`Failed to get available update data for [number] projects` message, you would then see the status of some modules in a grey box). You may also have to clear Drupal's cache first for this to work correctly.

The best thing to do is probably to [set up a cron job](http://drupal.org/cron) to run each hour (for example). This will progressively keep the status of all modules updated.

Another workaround would be to override the update_max_fetch_time value and set it to e.g. 30 seconds (you can set `$conf['update_max_fetch_time'] = 30;` in settings.php, or with Drush do `drush vset update_max_fetch_time 30`). But if a cron run is then triggered by poormanscron, this could lead to a long [page loading time](http://drupal.org/node/952394#comment-5242404).

This is from [issue 952394](http://drupal.org/node/952394) (still open).

Comment: Great answer. To avoid the timeout, you can also use drush pm-updatecode to check for and apply updates.  http://drupal.org/project/drush